# django doctests with transaction support?

Tags: django

I'd like to include some doctests that create objects in the database. I am using doctests instead of test cases since I want to show in a documentation to the user how they can manipulate the database.

Is there a way to wrap doctests with transactions? I suppose I can try to insert something at the start of each class and something at the end, but how do I know if they will be executed in that order?

Thanks.